# Android payment with paypal - Remove card

Tags: android, paypal

I'm using [Paypal SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK) for Android to allow for mobile payments in my app.Since i'm not interested for payments through cards i want to remove this option.I've tried setting `acceptCreditCards()` to false (`PayPalConfiguration`) and setting `exclude group: 'io.card'` in app's `build.gradle` dependency as it's suggested.

Although this does disable the button to pay with card, it still shows me the following screen before starting the next screen where the user is asked to enter his credentials.Can i somehow avoid this useless, in my case, screen?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For removing the card from the options, you have to add the below line to the configuration object of PayPal.

```
.acceptCreditCards(false)
```

Example :

```
PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
            .environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION)
            .clientId(PayPalConstant.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID)
            // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
            .merchantName(PayPalConstant.PAYPAL_MERCHANT_NAME).acceptCreditCards(false);
```